# "arrive" Vs. "reach" what are the differences if any?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, word-difference, synonyms

In the past I've been told that there is a difference between the usage of these two verbs: "**arrive**" and "**reach**", But I've never understood it. Today Iv'e checked it in the Cambridge dictionary and I found that they are considering synonyms:

> **[Reach](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reach?q=REACH)**: to *arrive* at a place, especially **after spending a long time or a lot of effort travelling**.
>
> **[Arrive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arrive)**: to reach a place, especially at the **end of a journey**.

But By googling I've reached / arrived [this site](https://www.italki.com/question/219346), which the writer there write the following things:

> REACH and ARRIVE are very similar, they imply you made it to the final
>   destination. I reached my goal, I arrived home.
>
> **REACH** implies you were farther away and you finally reached the destination. Often it is used in a context **where there were
>   difficulties in the way.** But not necessarily. It implies the goal is
>   achieved, you reached your destination. e.g. "Despite the storm on the sea we reached the shore safe and sound."
>
> **ARRIVE** means you got there. It is used also in a **context of
>   transportation, like planes, buses, trains.** e.g. I arrived at 10 / The
>   bus is scheduled to arrive at 10.

Now, my question is if based on that they are synonyms, can I use them interchangeably or they are not synonyms and I have to use each one of them in a certain context. Very often I find myself thinking about If I should use "arrive" or "reach". So far, I have no really clear information about it.

Answer (score 5):

These are mostly synonymous, at least when talking about the end of some *journey*.

> My GPS is telling me, "You have **reached** your destination."
>
> My GPS is telling me, "You have **arrived at** your destination."

*Metaphorically*, while "arrive" is often just a description of events, "reach" can imply some sort of *effort* or *unusual extension* (related to its other definitions) so it can sound slightly more *dramatic*.

> After a journey of many days, they finally **reached** the castle.

This is subtle, though.  If you really want to imply effort there are more dramatic verbs.

> Parched and weary after crossing the desert, they **stumbled into** the oasis.

Answer (score 0):

Arrive and reach are synonyms. However, arrive takes the preposition at, while reach doesn't.